# deploying puppeteer automation for a bill summary website

Tags: javascript, reactjs, git, puppeteer

I wrote a simple puppeteer code to log into websites and retrieve the amount due. I would like to build this into a website where my roommates can log in to view the breakdown of total due and have a cash app QR code embedded. I am hoping to turn this into a showcase project with responsive React and Firebase Auth.

This code file currently has login id and password written in and for obvious reasons I did not upload this to github. From what I read even private github repositories are not truly private?

How do I go about deploying this project while keeping the login info secure? I've been using cloudflare pages and it looks like only option for deployment is for me to create a git repository. Thank you.

Comment: You can't deploy puppeteer projects with cloudflare pages, you need a real backend. If you rent a VPS you can put the repo there but I would go with the private github repo if I were you. Also, this question probably doesn't belong here so expect it to get closed.

Comment: hey! i came across this because i'm looking to do the same for multiple sites. i just wanted to let you know that you can host Puppeteer on Firebase functions. you'll have to extend the timeout time on the Firebase function to as long as possible (9 mins) so that puppeteer has time to spin up, load websites, and scrape data. Firebase functions are much more powerful than people realize. and I think few know that they specifically support Puppeteer.

Comment: if you're using Firebase for authentication, you might as well use it for hosting your page. their page hosting is perfectly capable, and setting it up is super easy. i've built a large, relatively complex single page app entirely in the Firebase ecosystem and find it pretty nice.